# Avoiding all items rerendering when updating some items in list

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

really need you help here

I'm loosing a lot of time trying to optimize my app, I think there's something I'm not getting about React

Here's a typical case : I got a form with some interconnected inputs (Changing an input can disabled/enabled anothers)
Something looking like my code :

```
const Form = (form)=>{  
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(form.inputs)
  const updateInputs = (updates)=>{
    /**
     * Changing some inputs
     */
  }

  return inputs.map(input=>
    <InputComponent {...input} key={input.id} onChange={updateInputs}></InputComponent>
  )
}
```

My problem is when input is changed, all inputs are rerendering.

Memo/PureComponent is useless here because of the updateInputs function

Can't use "useCallback" hook on "updateInputs" because it's caching "inputs" state, which is updated every change

And yes I use React profiler.

I got the same issue with checkbox list & radio list.
Everytime I got a list with a state shared between items, I got this issue.

Comment: [This article](https://blog.goncharov.page/react-lifting-state-up-is-killing-your-app) speaks about your problem. If your state is outside of your list and every component depends on state, every state change triggers a re-render in all components. His solution is to set up a non-React class to manage state, then manually trigger component re-renders. It's _not_ a very common React pattern and may cause developer headache to maintain. You also might be pre-maturely optimizing. If it's working, and no one is complaining, then maybe its best to follow the regular React patterns.

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit
Wow, thank you so much for this article. It showed me how to fix my issue. 
I simply needed to put useCallback on "updateInputs", but mostly use a callback in setInputs !!! 
Like : setInputs((oldInputs)=>/*update inputs*/)
I will answer my question myself, but thanks to you and this article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @HaveSpacesuit and [this article](https://blog.goncharov.page/react-lifting-state-up-is-killing-your-app) (not the whole article, just the step #4)

My issue was : i couldn't put useCallback on "updateInputs" because I was making something like :

```
  const updateInputs = useCallback((updates)=>{
    const localInputs = [...inputs]
    /* update localInputs */
    setInputs(localInputs)
  }, [])
```

But doing this would memoize "inputs" state without refreshing it.

Setting "inputs" in the useCallback parameters would create a new function reference every update, which makes useCallback useless.

The solution is :

```
  const updateInputs = useCallback((updates)=>{
    setInputs((oldInputs)=>{
      const localInputs = [...oldInputs]
      /*update localInputs*/
      return localInputs
    }
  }, [])
```

Like this, the function will update fresh "inputs", and the function will keep his reference between rerenders thanks to useCallback.

I went from ~200ms to ~25ms on every user interaction